# Angular.js get form as data structure?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

**What I try to get done:**

The framework I'm using is generating by default these kind of input names by convention:

```
name="data[Model][field]
```

Here is an example of the form structure where a "Class has many Students":

```
name="data[Class][name]"
name="data[Student][0][name]"
name="data[Student][1][name]"
```

My problem is now how the heck to I get this structure reflected in my angulars $scope?

I'm expecting the same structure to somehow show up in $scope.data or something else like:

```
$scope.data: {
    Class: {
        name: 'Some Name',
    },
    Student: [
        {
            name: 'Some Name'
        },
        /* ... */
    ]
}
```

**What I've tried:**

I've tried to give the form the name "data" because I read somewhere this is picked up as another scope and the fields would appear within that scope. After that I've tried to use `ng-model="data.Model.field"` for each field. The best I could get back is an object like this (copied from the console):

```
Jc { $error={...}, $name="formData", $dirty=false, more...}
```

I think this is the angular form handler (?), I've checked the documentation as well, but I could not figure out how to access my forms data through it nor how to turn it into the structure I want.

Also every example for form handling I found for angular was different, it looks like there a thousand different ways to deal with forms. Guess I've just got lost.

- So is it possible to do what I want at all?
- Does what I want makes sense at all?
- If yes: How can I do it?
- If not: How do I deal the best with forms?

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you could install Batarang (the angularjs debugger) to check the values of the scope from the browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to recreate the object, the form could look something like this, and be available in $scope.data.

```
    $scope.data = {};

    <form>
        <input ng-model='data.Class.name'/>                    
        <input ng-repeat='student in data.Student' ng-model='student.name'/>
        <input type='submit'/>
    </form>
```

Comment: Not exactly. Is there no way to automatically read the whole form data directly from the form into a scope? :( I've already extended the frameworks form helper to inject ng-model, but I would appreciate it if I could *simply* the the whole form data with a simple method call or at least a single line of code.